# Location of methods and classes in Python3 interpreter

Tags: python, interpreter, language-implementation

Our professor told us today that we can build an iterator, e.g.

```
class IteratorExample:
    def __init__(self, n):
       pass

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if cond:
            pass
        else:
            raise StopIteration
```

and that when we will use it, as in (for i in iteratorExample), the interpreter will call the __iter__(self) and __next__(self) methods. My questions are:

1. If I open C:\Python folder - where can I see the code that calls these methods?
2. In the python folder, where can I see the code of other built-in methods  (like len(), or int()?

Comment: You better ask this your prof :)

Comment: What do you mean, see the code that calls these methods? *You* need to write that code.

Comment: I did, he told me he isn't sure :-) and also, that the interpreter for python is written in Python..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could look at the Python byte code disassembly, to see how `for`-loop is implemented in Python:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis('for x in it: pass')
  1           0 SETUP_LOOP              14 (to 17)
              3 LOAD_NAME                0 (it)
              6 GET_ITER
        >>    7 FOR_ITER                 6 (to 16)
             10 STORE_NAME               1 (x)
             13 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            7
        >>   16 POP_BLOCK
        >>   17 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             20 RETURN_VALUE
```

Even without looking at the source, we could guess that `__iter__` is called by `GET_ITER` op code and `__next__` is called in `FOR_ITER`.

And indeed, CPython's [Python/ceval.c](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/4e8ac4173b3c/Python/ceval.c#l2646) confirms it e.g., `GET_ITER` calls [`PyObject_GetIter(iterable)`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_GetIter) that is equivalent to `iter(iterable)` that can call `iterable.__iter__()` method.

---

> In the python folder, where can I see the code of other built-in methods (like len(), or int()?

These functions are also implemented in C (in CPython). You can see them in the [CPython source repository](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/default).

Built-in methods are from `builtins` module that is implemented in [Python/bltinmodule.c e.g., `len()`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/1c51f1650c42/Python/bltinmodule.c#l1827) calls [`PyObject_Size()`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_Length).

`int` is a class for integers in Python. It is implemented in [Objects/longobject.c](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/1c51f1650c42/Objects/longobject.c#l4340) (Python 3).

---

> Isn't the CPython code in the Python folder?

No. The Python installation folder does not contain the source code for CPython. It may contain pure Python modules from the standard library such as [Lib/fractions.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/fractions.py) unless they are zipped or only compiled modules such as `.pyc`, `.pyo` files have been installed.

To get the full source code, run:

```
$ hg clone https://hg.python.org/cpython
```

where `hg` is the [Mercurial executable](http://mercurial.selenic.com/).

As an exercise, you could locate where other [Python implementations](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonImplementations) such as Pypy, Jython define `GET_ITER`, `FOR_ITER`, `len()`, `int()`.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the effort. One more problem - When I search (with Windows Grep, not the puny Windows Search)  my C:\Python34 folder for, example, the expression 'builtin_len', or for 'GET_ITER', which is used in the CPython script, the search returns no results. Isn't the CPython code in the Python folder? N.B. of course, I've downloaded Python from www.python.org and I use the latest version

Answer (score 0):

You're asking for behaviour that's built into Python. In particular you're using the Python interpreter written in C which is often referred to as CPython. You can find the source of CPython [here](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/1c51f1650c42) although it'll take a while to find the exact code that does `len()`, `int()` and the iterator protocol.